# Efficient algorithm for sorting objects by key that are range from 0 to 100 for big input sizes

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I have the following class that represents students info:

```
struct Student
{
    std::string name;
    int id = 0;
    short rank = 0;
};
```

The field `rating`  can be any number from `0` to `100`.
I need to implement the following function that sorts students in descending order:

```
void fast_sort(std::vector<Student>& students)
{
  // TODO:
}
```

Can I do the sort somehow in-place? What's the most efficient approach for big size inputs?

I have already tried to count the number of students for each rating:

```
std::map<short, int> counter;
for(size_t i = 0; i < students.size(); ++i)
{
    short rank = students[i].rank;
    ++counter[rank];
}
```

Now I am thinking about the way to put students on the right place without using additional `std::vector`.

Comment: Counting sort..

Comment: You are not allowed to use std::sort?

Comment: @magmine Using `std::sort` in this case is not the most efficient way to sort `students`.

Comment: Yes indeed counting sort would be the most efficient in this case

Comment: Counting sort. And you're shooting yourself in the foot efficiency-wise if that `rating` (aka. `rank`, apparently) domain really is 1..100. A map would make more sense if there were no restricted domain, certainly not one that small, and at that point `std::sort` would be your best option anyway.

Comment: please clarify in the question that you are looking for something better than `std::sort` (because efficient it is). And note that even a `O(N)` sorting would not necessarily be faster than `std::sort` for considerably small input sizes. Did you actually try `std::sort` and have evidence that it takes too much time?

Comment: @idclev463035818 I am talking about big input sizes and the sort algorithms implementation that faster than `std::sort` for this case.

Comment: "I am talking about big input sizes and the sort algorihms implementation that faster than std::sort for this case"  I don't see any of that in the question, thats why I suggested you to clarify the quesiton

Comment: you see, now you got an answer that is fine for the question you asked, but not for the question you actually wanted to ask ;)

Comment: @idclev463035818 that you so much, I have added this additional information to the title and description.

Comment: "Using std::sort in this case is not the most efficient way to sort students" lacks evidence.  Anyways, rather than focus on sorting only, consider the higher level problem of efficient access to all `struct Student` related functions.  I suspect if `sort()` is not fast enough, consider an BST/AVL tree.

Answer (score 4):

The `std::sort` [function](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) might be useful for you since it allows using a user defined comparison function as in the following example :

```cpp
// sort algorithm example
#include <algorithm>    // std::sort
#include <vector>       // std::vector
#include "Student.h" // your Student's class header

bool myfunction (const Student& x, const Student& y) { 
  return (x.getRating()<y.getRating()); 
}

int main () {
  
  std::vector<Student> myStudents;
  
  // fill your Students vector with your logic

  // using myfunction as comp
  std::sort (myStudents.begin(), myStudents.end(), myfunction);  

  return 0;
}
```

Its time complexity is in `O(nlog(n))`, no better than the best performing known general sorting algorithm.

Comment: its not that clear in the question, but OP is looking for something better than `std::sort`. Note that `std::sort` is very efficient in the general case, but when the input is from a limited range then there are algorithms with lower complexity available. You got my vote anyhow, because `std::sort` is efficient ;)

Answer (score 2):

### Counting sort

1. Count the number of students for each rank;
2. Use the cumulative counts to find the index of the first student of every rank;
3. Put the students at the first available index for their rank.

Each of these three steps has complexity *O(n+k)*, where *n* is the number of students and *k* the number of ranks.

I'll show an example with 10 students, with ranks going from 0 to 2 instead of 0 to 100.

```
# define NBSTUDENTS 10
# define NBRANKS 3

struct Student students[NBSTUDENTS] =
  {("Alice", 0),  ("Bob", 2),     ("Charlie", 1), ("Daenerys", 1), ("Eleonore", 2),
   ("Farouk", 1), ("Gabriel", 0), ("Hector", 1),  ("Iris", 2),     ("Julien", 2)};
```

1. Count the number of students for each rank

```
int count_per_rank[NBRANKS] = {2, 4, 4};
```

2. Use the cumulative counts to find the index of the first student of every rank

```
int available_index[NBRANKS] = {0, 0+2, 0+2+4};
```

You can use [`std::partial_sum` defined in header `<numeric>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sum) to get the cumulative counts; see [Surt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64969219/3080723).

3. Put the students at the first available index for their rank

```cpp
struct Student sorted_students[NBSTUDENTS] = {}
for (auto student = students.begin(); student < students.end(); ++student)
{
    sorted_students[available_index[student->rank]] = *student;
    available_index[student->rank]++;
}
```

### `std::sort`

The complexity of `std::sort` is *O(n log(n))*. The complexity of the counting sort above is *O(n+k)*. These *O( )* notation hide a constant; you can expect that constant to be much smaller for the well-optimised `std::sort` than for your custom implemented sort. When *n* tends towards infinity, *log(n)* also tends towards infinity. But *log* increases very slowly. How big is your big size input? I assume you have fewer than a million students. The binary logarithm of 1000000 is 20. If we assume *n < 1000000*, then *n log(n) < 20 n*. Are we really faster than `std::sort` with our custom counting sort?

Answer (score 1):

You have nearly solved it yourself, a little change to the counting code

(totally untested code)

```cpp
std::map<short, int> counter;
for(size_t i = 0; i < students.size(); ++i) {
    short rank = students[i].rank;
    ++counter[rank];
}
```

to

```cpp
std::array<int, Values> counter;
for(size_t i = 0; i < students.size(); ++i) {
    short rank = students[i].rank;
    ++counter[rank];
}
```

Where values is the number of contiguous different values 0..Values-1

Then use counting sort (the foundation of radix sort)

```cpp
std::array<int, Values> pos = {0};
std::partial_sum(counter.begin(), std::prev(counter.end()), std::next(pos.begin()));
```

Now you have the starting point of each rank.

```cpp
std::vector<Student> studs;
for (int i = studs.size(); i < studs.end(); ++i) {
  int wanted = pos[studs[i].rank];
  while (wanted != i) {
    pos[studs[i].rank]++;
    swap(studs[i], studs[wanted]);
    wanted = pos[studs[i].rank];
  }
}
```

Comment: I think using `std::partial_sum` like that gives an offset result; *i.e.*, it would transform `{2, 4, 3, 3}` into `{2, 6, 9, 12}`, but what you would want is `{0, 2, 6, 9}`.

Comment: @stef yes, that is correct ill find the right code in a moment.